# ImageMagick convert pdf to png with fixed width or height

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm converting PDF file to PNG using ImageMagick's convert in that way:

```
convert -density 150 file.pdf -quality 100 res.png
```

The problem is that the size of the result pictures different according to the file content. How can I choose a specific max height and max width in pixels to the result picture ?

Answer (score 5):

**Updated Answer**

From your comments, I think I understand better what you want now. So, I think the identity you need is this:

```
Required Resolution       Required Height
-------------------    =  ---------------
Current Resolution        Current Height
```

but remember that applies in both X- and Y-directions. So, let's let ImageMagick work out the x-resolution and the y-resolution you need to get your desired output size - it is easier to do it with ImageMagick's `fx` method because that works on both Windows and Linux and I happen to know you have ImageMagick installed already, whereas you may not have `bc` or anything on Windows to do maths:

```
#!/bin/bash
# New width and new height that you want
nh=1000
nw=500

# Calculate Resolution needed in Height
rh=$(identify -format "%[fx:int(($nh*resolution.y)/h)]" doc.pdf)
echo $rh

# Calculate Resolution needed in Width
rw=$(identify -format "%[fx:int(($nw*resolution.x)/w)]" doc.pdf)
echo $rw
```

So, if I use that on a file called `doc.pdf` that measures 595x842, it outputs 85 and 60 for the x and y density. And if I then use

```
convert -density 85 doc.pdf a.jpg
```

it comes out at 702x994 - which is close to the height of 1000 I wanted

and if I use

```
convert -density 60 doc.pdf a.jpg
```

it comes out at 496x702 which is close to the width of 500 I wanted.

In the foregoing, you can just use:

```
identify -format "%[fx:int(($nh*resolution.y)/h)]" doc.pdf
```

rather than assign the result to a variable like I did -I just do that because I generally want to use the variable later.

**Original Answer**

Just add a `-resize WIDTHxHEIGHT` in there after the conversion to set the size you want. So, in concrete terms, if you want it no more than 1500x2000 whilst retaining the original aspect ratio, do:

```
convert -density 150 file.pdf -quality 100 -resize 1500x2000 res.png
```

If you want it no more than 800px wide, and don't care about the height, do:

```
convert -density 150 file.pdf -quality 100 -resize 800x res.png
```

If you want it no more than 1000px tall, and don't care about the width, do:

```
convert -density 150 file.pdf -quality 100 -resize x1000 res.png
```

If you like the *"Hall of Mirrors"* effect, and want it 1200x1800 come what may,  and to heck with the aspect ratio, do:

```
convert -density 150 file.pdf -quality 100 -resize 1200x1800! res.png
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm trying to make things faster and in your way it's converting to big file and then resize which may take a lot of time. For example density of 600 and resize of 100x100 would still take a lot of time until the big image is ready and then resize, in opposite to create the picture in the right size in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted your question as meaning you knew you wanted to use `-density 150` (because that is what you coded) and you then wanted to resize your images - rather than you wanted to speed up your processing by only using the minimum density... If you use the ImageMagick command `identify -verbose someFile.pdf` on your files, do they all have the same resolution? And is it 72x72? Because the output file size changes directly in proportion to the density.

Comment: I have updated my answer - please have another look. Also, if performance is a big issue with you, and you have lots of PDFs to convert, please consider using `GNU Parallel` if you are on a decent OS such as Linux or OSX.

Comment: why wouldn't this work in imagemagick 6? `convert -density X file.pdf file.png` will make the same size png for different density

Comment: answer - "reason was wrong position of the density parameter" - https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=34898